# HTML <table> Does Not Fill QLabel

Tags: html, stylesheet, pyqt5, qlabel

How can I make an html table to fill all the available space in the QLabel that the same html defines?

In this image the red should fill the black as the table being width and height at 100% should fill all of the available space of the QLabel which is in black:
[image: red=html black=resized QLabel]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lbl1 = QLabel("""
        <style>
            table{
                background-color: red;
            }

        </style>

        <table width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">1234</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="60">1</td>
                <td width="50">4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        """, self)
        lbl1.setStyleSheet('QFrame {background-color:black;}')

        lbl1.resize(200, 200)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 220)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use a vertical layout.

Comment: if I put the QLable in a QVBoxLayout nothing changes

Comment: According to the [Supported HTML Subset docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), relative values are only supported for the width, and not the height. The absolute width values you've set for the table-cells will override the relative table width.